# The .apply() method is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

So `friends` is a column with a list in each instance such as `df['friends][0] = [id1, id2, ..., idn]`. I'm trying to count the number of friends in a separate column such as `df['friend_counts'][0] = n`.

I did the following. I've used this code in other datasets, but for some reason it's taking forever and the dataset is only 300,000 instances.

```
df_user['friend_counts'] = df_user['friends'].apply(lambda x: len(df_user.friends[x]))
```

Also, for some reason this following code creates a `season` column but is not populated, i.e. it's all just blank spaces. This is troublesome since I did this exact same code for every other dataset. Did they change the `.apply()` method?

```
#Convert 'date' to a date time object
df_reviews["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_reviews["date"])
#Splitting up 'release_date' -> 'release_weekday', 'release_month', 
'release_year'
df_reviews["weekday"] = df_reviews["date"].dt.weekday_name
df_reviews["month"] = df_reviews["date"].dt.month
df_reviews["year"] = df_reviews["date"].dt.year
### Helper function
def season_converter(month_name):
""" Returns the season a particular month is in """
season = ""`enter code here`
#Winter
if month_name in ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec']:
    season = "Winter" 
#Spring
if month_name in ['Mar', 'Apr', 'May']:
    season = "Spring" 
#Summer
if month_name in ['Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug'] : 
    season = "Summer"
#Fall
if month_name in ['Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov']: 
    season = "Fall"
#Other
if month_name == "NA":
    season = "NA"
return season
#Create a new column that holds seasonal information
df_reviews['season'] = df_reviews['month'].apply(lambda x: 
season_converter(x))
```

Comment: A brief scan of your code reveals that the season_converter() function receives a month name which is a string, but you are passing an integer to it (df_reviews['month']) in your lambda function.

Comment: @floydn you're right, I think I forgot to add in another helper function when copying and pasting. In terms of the `friends` code, it's just computationally intensive right? I just need to wait for it to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dictionary` for improve performance:

```
d = {1:'Winter', 2:'Winter', 12:'Winter', 3: 'Spring', .... np.nan:'NA', 'NA':'NA'}
df_reviews['season'] = df_reviews['month'].map(d)
```

Another solution if is possible use numeric seasons:

```
df_reviews['season'] = (df_reviews['month'] % 12 + 3) // 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know what might be wrong with the 'friends' part? Is it just computationally intensive?

Comment: @handavidbang - yes, exactly. also there is problem function have inputs numeric months, not `Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec'`